# limiting access to third party app in google ads api

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

I have multiple Google ads account(multiple google ads account associated with one email account) . If I give access of my google ads account  to third party app will they have access to all the google ads account?

If the third party app can access all of my  google ads account how do I restrict them to access only 1 account that I want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to restrict OAuth2 access to just a single of your Google Ads accounts. I'd recommend to create a new Google account which only has access to the Google Ads account in question and use that to authenticate with the third party app.

Comment: Can you please share some doc link where this is mentioned?

Comment: I don't think this is documented as such. It's just a consequence of how Google Ads access permissions work. OAuth2 credentials inherit all permissions of the Google account granting them, so if you want those credentials to only be able to access a single Ads account, you also need the Google account to only have that access.

Comment: Pleasure. Please accept the answer if it helps you to solve the issue.